# Separate tensorflow dataset to different outputs in tensorflow2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset with 3 tensor outputs of data, label and path:

```
import tensorflow as tf #tensroflow version 2.1

data=tf.constant([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[8,9],[9,0]],name='data')
labels=tf.constant([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],name='label')
path=tf.constant(['p0','p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8','p9'],name='path')
my_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data,labels,path))
```

I want to separate `my_dataset` back to 3 datasets of data, labels and paths (or 3 tensors) without iterating over it and without converting it to numpy.

In tensorflow 1.X this is done simply using

```
d,l,p=my_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

and then converting the tensors to datasets. How to do it in tensorflow2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found does not look very "pythonic" but it works.
I used the `map()` method:

```
data= my_dataset.map(lambda x,y,z:x)
labels= my_dataset.map(lambda x,y,z:y)
paths= my_dataset.map(lambda x,y,z:z)
```

After this separation, the order of the labels stays the same.